# How can "Community" post a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, community

The post
[How to unhide 'Very Hidden' Worksheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1254447/how-to-unhide-very-hidden-worksheet)
has a bounty posted by
[Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community), which says:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

As Community is not a person and has no reputation,
I am very puzzled by this bounty and am looking for an explanation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The user who posted the bounty got deleted - and that left the bounty in place. with community as the owner, since deleted users get merged with community.

I've refunded the bounty, just so its less confusing.

Comment: Refund to whom? Community? So he has now 51 reputation instead of 1? Cool! Seems he has already used his new powers and downvoted 25 questions.

Comment: Things do get very strange here.

Comment: @ThomasWeller How can you see that Community has downvoted 25 questions? Downvotes are private.

Btw, some fun facts I found out: The top user at hardwarerecs.SE would be on 44577th place in SO and the Community user would be #1 on pretty much all sites (didn't check all). Just from the edits alone it would have more than three times as much reputation as Jon Skeet.

Comment: He's joking - refunded's the term I think the UI uses and that indicates community got back the reputation, but the reputation more or less went into the bitbucket.

Comment: @Fabian Aren't you forgetting the rep-cap?

Comment: That's true. Without it, Jon Skeet would probably have more rep than all community users together.

Comment: @Fabian I do not want to be the fun killer here, but after you reach 2000 rep the edits you make are free, no 2 rep reward.